# Incrementing an array

Tags: java, arrays

Simple question I was just wondering how I should go about increasing an array by one element without changing the name of the array?
I know that it will involve creating a temporary array but I'm not sure how to construct my code
Thanks

Comment: Which language? What do you mean "increasing an array", do you mean making it larger?

Comment: Java and yes making it larger. If it originally contained 4 elements I want it now to contain 5.

Comment: any code you have also helps....

Comment: You can't in java to increase an array by one element without changing the name. Instead you can use an ArrayList.

Comment: why don't you use a data structure that allows for dynamic resizing (e.g. a list)?

Comment: You'll want to use one of the list collections, such as [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Please show some code, that you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Java Arrays API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). It has a method `copyOf` that allows you to create resized copies of arrays. The original array can't be changed with it, though.

If you have to do this, however, I recommend you to listen to the advice in the comments and use a `List` datastructure such as `ArrayList`. It's easier, less error-prone and likely even more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, arrays in Java have a fixed dimension once you create them; that is: you can't increase (or decrease) the size of the array once it has been created.

Some alternatives are:

1. Create a second array with the desired dimension and copy the entries from one array to the other
2. Use a collection; specifically an `ArrayList`

For option 1:

```
int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] myNewArray = new int[myArray.length + 1];
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    myNewArray[i] = myArray[i];
/*
 * Notice that the last entry of myNewArray is empty
 */
```

For option 2... check [the Java Collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).